# "Open source" as a verb

Tags: verbs, orthography, hyphenation

I encountered a problem when I started to write a report including some notes on open source software.

The problem I have is if I can use *open source* as a verb like:

> We open sourced some software product.

How should this be written — I mean in one word or with hyphen, etc.? Is there a different way to express the same idea? Is there a standard English expression for this?

Comment: "We released some software products as open source." would be an alternative way to express the same action.

Comment: Also: this is not just an English-language question, because the term "open sourced" is quite loaded: it can mean about half a dozen different (but related) things.

Comment: @JoachimSauer : you can elaborate its 'loading' in an answer.

Comment: I will, when I find the time, hopefully later today.

Comment: When verbing a compound noun or noun pair it is customary to hyphenate (*We open-sourced the project.* *They green-lighted the film.*) or simply combine the terms without hyphens (*We opensourced the project.* *They greenlighted the film*). The march toward un-hyphened word amalgams is usually swift, especially in technology.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I wouldn’t say that [open source](http://opensource.org/) is particularly overloaded.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking through [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=opensource&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=opensourced&oq=opensourced&gs_l=serp.3...2369.2369.0.3305.1.1.0.0.0.0.301.301.3-1.1.0...0.0...1c.VYcAgaD1z60&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=182d50f29001f36a&biw=1111&bih=627), it appears that a few authors do use *open-source* as a verb. Some of them use it within quotes, while others use a hyphen-less one word variant. It has also made its way into [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/open-source), but, just to make things difficult, is accompanied by an [alternative form](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/open_source). I think it might be OK to use *open-source* as a verb and depending on the audience and frequency of usage, wrap it within quotes.

That said, there are a few standard ways of expressing the 'open-sourcing' of a product which will not raise any bushy grammarian eyebrows. Here are a few:

> We released our product under an open source licence.
>
> We released the source code under an open licence.
>
> We shared the project with the community using an open licence.
>
> We made the source code available to the community using a [GPL] licence.

... and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I think the use of ***open-source*** as a verb, withour further clarification, invites trouble.  The term includes a verb form, *source*, which generally means to obtain goods or services from a particular provider or *source* (used as a noun).

Logically, *We **open-sourced** the software* could then mean,

*We obtained the code from someone who allows others to freely use her/his materials, standards etc.*

or it could mean

*We issued the code to allows others to freely use our materials, standards etc.*

Comment: You're right about two possible interpretations, but I'm not sure that's quite the same as "inviting trouble." Aren't many English words like that? _She lost her pump in the fall_ could mean a few different things.  Good consideration, though.

Comment: @J.R. - I agree that "inviting trouble" is a bit strong. I think we often relish subtley and even ambiguity. But in this context, trying to define the permissive status of something, more clarity is probably desirable.